# The optimal way to stratify a numerical target variable into a categorical one for a machine learning algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, regression, k-means

I have tabular data, the predictive variables are numerical and categorical and the target variable is a numerical one. Using the proper techniques I can make predictive models with R^2=0.95.

Now let's imagine I want to test similar techniques by considering the predictive variable a categorical one, that is, making the regression problem a classificational one.

The first thing I can do is for a number of labels, take the percentiles (For example if I want 4 different labels, I could take the quantiles)

The second thing is to study the distribution of the target variable, and, if let's say its a multinomial distrubution with 3 different modes where almost all data concentrates around those three "peaks" it's obvious that the most intelligent thing is to take three different labels centered in those modes (low, medium and high) .

But now let's set out the next problem rigorously. Let's imagine that the target variable is the price of something. Let's imagine I decide to divide the target variable in 5 categories (Very cheap, cheap, medium, expensive and very expensive) asigning for each category a numerical range (let's say that for very cheap is below 20.000$)

It's obvious that If I make two prediction models, one a regressional one with the numerical variable and the other a classificational one with the stratify target variable in 5 labels, and I take one observation of the test set (with all its respective values of the predictive variables), there is a higher chance of classification sucess if i use the first model and I predict the numerical value of the price and then assign it its respective label, that if I directly apply the classification model to the data

This is obviously because when you divide the numerical target into labels you are losing information (it's not the same saying that a number is 34000 that a number lies between the range of 20000 and 40000.

So my question is, how do I select the number of labels and what ranges in order minimize that information loss? Let's mind I have R^2=0.95 so with the good choose of ranges, I must have a very high classification F1.

I think clusterization using the predictive variables can be very useful, but I don't know how to apply it well.

Sorry for the messy text, I think this could be redacted better but my English is limited. Any idea very appreciated. I think this kind of problems must have been considered before so if this issue have a name I can google I will thankful.

Comment: Why do you want to do this anyway? As you say yourself, by binning the numerical variable you lose important information, so why do that?

Comment: For a project. I want to compare the efficacy of different machine learning algorithms both for regression and classification, but I don't want to lose time in the exposition by doing twice the exploratory analysis so I would prefer to do it in the same dataset.

Comment: I don't think this is a very useful task, for one the two results will not be comparable, because of different metrics, and second, as you alluded to, this becomes a whole task on its own, figuring out how to bin this variable. There is no standard way to do this because it's not standard, you will have to spend time figuring this out for each problem.

Comment: It's not about comparing regression vs classification, but comparing different methods in both regression and classification without having to do twice the exploratory analysis in different datasets.